# I can't push to my repository it says Your branch is up-to-date with 'upstream/master' but I have made changes to my files

Tags: git, gitlab

I can't push to my GITLAB repository I am get this when trying to push to my repository. There was not any problems a few days ago pushing to my repository.

```
C:\projects\304cem>git commit -m"whatever"
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'upstream/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   config/helperFunctions.js
        modified:   controllers/setupController.js
        modified:   controllers/userController.js
        modified:   package.json

Untracked files:
        node_modules/.bin/_mocha
        node_modules/.bin/_mocha.cmd
        node_modules/.bin/forever
        node_modules/.bin/forever.cmd
        node_modules/.bin/mocha
        node_modules/.bin/mocha.cmd
        node_modules/forever/
        node_modules/mocha/

no changes added to commit
```

Comment: "no changes added to commit" - forget to `add`? If there is no new local node/commit it will be up-to-date. Changes that are not in a commit and part of the branch lineage do not count.

Comment: @user2864740 I have, I typed in git add -A.  It adds all my node modules but I still cant't push it.

Comment: `add` (stage changes) then `commit` (create a commit/node on the current tip from the staged changes) then `push` (update remote repository from local commits). If there is a problem with the push, show that: there are three distinct actions and each one has a different purpose/interaction. The post does *not* show a push - and thus cannot show an error with pushing. It is a friendly reminder from git.

Comment: @user2864740 when I type in git push it just returns Everything up-to-date

Comment: `add`, `commit`, `push`: Without the add the commit does nothing. Without the commit the push does nothing.

Comment: @user2864740 but I have added the files using git add -A

Answer (score 0):

You changes are currently unstaged, do a `git add .` to stage them for commit. 
To make sure that you have indeed staged your changes, do `git status`. This should show you changes staged for commit.

If you don't want to explicitly stage files for commit, use the -a flag while committing. This will automatically stage your changes and commit.

```
git commit -a -m "message"
```